# Trapezoidal wave in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

How do I generate a trapezoidal wave in Python?

I looked into the modules such as SciPy and NumPy, but in vain. Is there a module such as the scipy.signal.gaussian which returns an array of values representing the Gaussian function wave?

[image]

I generated this using the trapezoidal kernel of [Astropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astropy), 
**Trapezoid1DKernel(30,slope=1.0)**
. I want to implement this in Python without using Astropy.

Comment: What parameters does your trapezodial wave have?

Comment: Just the width and the slope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the width and the slope are sufficient to define a triangular signal, you would need a third parameter for a trapezoidal signal: the amplitude.

Using those three parameters, you can easily adjust the `scipy.signal.sawtooth` function to give you a trapeziodal shape by truncating and offsetting the triangular shaped function.

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def trapzoid_signal(t, width=2., slope=1., amp=1., offs=0):
    a = slope*width*signal.sawtooth(2*np.pi*t/width, width=0.5)/4.
    a[a>amp/2.] = amp/2.
    a[a<-amp/2.] = -amp/2.
    return a + amp/2. + offs

t = np.linspace(0, 6, 501)
plt.plot(t,trapzoid_signal(t, width=2, slope=2, amp=1.), label="width=2, slope=2, amp=1")
plt.plot(t,trapzoid_signal(t, width=4, slope=1, amp=0.6), label="width=4, slope=1, amp=0.6")

plt.legend( loc=(0.25,1.015))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that you may also like to define a phase, depeding on the use case.

In order to define a single pulse, you might want to modify the function a bit and supply an array which ranges over `[0,width]`.

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def trapzoid_signal(t, width=2., slope=1., amp=1., offs=0):
    a = slope*width*signal.sawtooth(2*np.pi*t/width, width=0.5)/4.
    a += slope*width/4.
    a[a>amp] = amp
    return a + offs

for w,s,a in zip([2,5], [2,1], [1,0.6]):
    t = np.linspace(0, w, 501)
    l = "width={}, slope={}, amp={}".format(w,s,a)
    plt.plot(t,trapzoid_signal(t, width=w, slope=s, amp=a), label=l)

plt.legend( loc="upper right")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This looks handy. Can youplease tell me how to generate a single pulse only of a particular width. I wanted to implement the image I attached in the question. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much. Did some edits and finally got it done.

Answer (score 2):

From the [SciPy website](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html#waveforms) it looks like this isn't included (they currently have `sawtooth` and `square`, but not trapezoid). As a generalised version of [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041498/equation-for-trapezoidal-wave-equation) C example the following will do what you want,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def trapezoidalWave(xin, width=1., slope=1.):
    x = xin%(4*width)
    if (x <= width):
        # Ascending line
        return x*slope;
    elif (x <= 2.*width):
        # Top horizontal line
        return width*slope
    elif (x <= 3.*width):
        # Descending line
        return 3.*width*slope - x*slope
    elif (x <= 4*width):
        # Bottom horizontal line
        return 0.


x = np.linspace(0.,20,1000)
for i in x:
    plt.plot(i, trapezoidalWave(i), 'k.')
    plt.plot(i, trapezoidalWave(i, 1.5, 2.), 'r.')
plt.show()
```

which looks like,

[image]

This can be done more elegantly with Heaviside functions which allow you to use NumPy arrays,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def H(x):
    return 0.5 * (np.sign(x) + 1)

def trapWave(xin, width=1., slope=1.):
    x = xin%(4*width)
    y = ((H(x)-H(x-width))*x*slope +
         (H(x-width)-H(x-2.*width))*width*slope +
         (H(x-2.*width)-H(x-3.*width))*(3.*width*slope - x*slope))
    return y

x = np.linspace(0.,20,1000)
plt.plot(x, trapWave(x))
plt.plot(x, trapWave(x, 1.5, 2.))
plt.show()
```

For this example, the Heaviside version is about 20 times faster!

Answer (score 2):

The below example shows how to do that to get points and show scope.

Equation based on reply: [Equation for trapezoidal wave equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041498/equation-for-trapezoidal-wave-equation)

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def get_wave_point(x, a, m, l, c):
    # Equation from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041498/equation-for-trapezoidal-wave-equation
    # a/pi(arcsin(sin((pi/m)x+l))+arccos(cos((pi/m)x+l)))-a/2+c
    # a is the amplitude
    # m is the period
    # l is the horizontal transition
    # c is the vertical transition

    point = a/math.pi*(math.asin(math.sin((math.pi/m)*x+l))+math.acos(math.cos((math.pi/m)*x+l)))-a/2+c
    return point

print('Testing wave')

x = np.linspace(0., 10, 1000)
listofpoints = []
for i in x:
    plt.plot(i, get_wave_point(i, 5, 2, 50, 20), 'k.')
    listofpoints.append(get_wave_point(i, 5, 2, 50, 20))
print('List of points : {} '.format(listofpoints))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole credit goes to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest . I am just revising some edits to his code which just made my day.

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np

def trapzoid_signal(t, width=2., slope=1., amp=1., offs=0):
    a = slope*width*signal.sawtooth(2*np.pi*t/width, width=0.5)/4.
    a += slope*width/4.
    a[a>amp] = amp
    return a + offs

for w,s,a in zip([32],[1],[0.0322]):
    t = np.linspace(0, w, 34)

    plt.plot(t,trapzoid_signal(t, width=w, slope=s, amp=a))


plt.show()
```

The result:[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw a very late hat into this ring, namely, a function using only numpy that produces a single (symmetric) trapezoid at a desired location, with all the usual parameters. Also posted [here](https://gist.github.com/CianMRoche/10f259bf8812e650d1e23fae256e52dd)

```
import numpy as np

def trapezoid(x, center=0, slope=1, width=1, height=1, offset=0):
    """
    For given array x, returns a (symmetric) trapezoid with plateau at y=h (or -h if 
    slope is negative), centered at center value of "x".
    Note: Negative widths and heights just converted to 0

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : array_like
        array of x values at which the trapezoid should be evaluated
    center : float
        x coordinate of the center of the (symmetric) trapezoid
    slope : float
        slope of the sides of the trapezoid
    width : float
        width of the plateau of the trapezoid
    height : float
        (positive) vertical distance between the base and plateau of the trapezoid
    offset : array_like
        vertical shift (either single value or the same shape as x) to add to y before returning

    Returns
    -------
    y : array_like
        y value(s) of trapezoid with above parameters, evaluated at x

    """
    
    # ---------- input checking ----------
    if width < 0: width = 0
    if height < 0: height = 0

    x = np.asarray(x)

    slope_negative = slope < 0
    slope = np.abs(slope)  #  Do all calculations with positive slope, invert at end if necessary

    # ---------- Calculation ----------
    y = np.zeros_like(x)
    mask_left = x - center < -width/2.0
    mask_right = x - center > width/2.0

    y[mask_left] = slope*(x[mask_left] - center + width/2.0)
    y[mask_right] = -slope*(x[mask_right] - center - width/2.0)

    y += height     # Shift plateau up to y=h
    y[y < 0] = 0    # cut off below zero (so that trapezoid flattens off at "offset")

    if slope_negative: y = -y          # invert non-plateau

    return y + offset
```

Which outputs something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("seaborn-colorblind")

x = np.linspace(-5,5,1000)

for i in range(1,4):
    plt.plot(x,trapezoid(x, center=0, slope=1, width=i, height=i, offset = 0), label=f"width = height = {i}\nslope=1")

plt.plot(x,trapezoid(x, center=0, slope=-1, width=2.5, height=1, offset = 0), label=f"width = height = 1.5,\nslope=-1")
plt.ylim((-2.5,3.5))
plt.legend(frameon=False, loc='lower center', ncol=2)
```

Example output:

[image]