# Is there a way of creating a rectangular signal with a given rising edge?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signals

I need some help with creating a rectangular signal. I just can't get my head around this, so I am hoping that you can help out.
Basically I want to create a signal using numpy and scipy. The signal in question should be a rectangular signal with a rising and a falling edge, so basically a trapezoid. The question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539696/trapezoidal-wave-in-python), but when I try to insert rise times and a period smaller than 1 it doesn't work anymore.

Also, if you can think of a handy way of creating a signal with a rise time **and** some overshooting any idea is appreciated.

Comment: For the overshooting you could just use the Fourier decomposition up to a certain degree

Comment: That is because of rasterization / units issues. The signal is just a (coarse) representation of the trapezoidal wave, which is basically an array where the values represent the (mean?) height of the signal at that position. It is then customary to express the widths in units of the array cells, which are integers. If you try to use non-integer values, some of the precision is lost, typically truncated, meaning that if your widths are below 1 they become 0, and the key features of your signal may no longer be recognizable.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](/help/mre)? Or even leave a comment on the answer you are trying from the question you linked, as you see fit.